# Firefox Selenium webdriver for play framework: How to upgrade?

Tags: playframework, selenium-webdriver, playframework-2.0

I get the error: Firefox Webdriver 2.32.0 is incompatible with Firefox 30.0
How can I upgrade the firefox webdriver? The Selenium firefox doesn't use my profile, it uses some other profile.

Here's what I've tried: Search for webdriver jars in the play framework software package, unzip them and look for .xpi (firefox addon file-extension), but no luck there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to `libraryDependencies` within your `build.sbt` or `Build.scala`:

```
 "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.44.0" % "test"
```

If you're not using this within the `test` scope (i.e. for browser testing within Play), then remove `% "test"`.

2.44.0 appears to be the latest version for Selenium drivers, but you may need to fiddle with the version to find one that's compatible with your version of Firefox.